# When should you remove water base grout sealer residue?

Tags: flooring, tile, grout

Tried sealing some of my grout today using 511 impregnator water base but there was some that got on the tiles and left a residue after wiping that I didn’t see till I was far away. I know the back of the bottle says that you can clean up residue by adding water and buffing with a soft nylon pad, but it also says to let cure for 24 to 72 hours. So should I clean that residue as soon as I see it or wait a day to clean the floor?

Comment: razor blade......

Answer (score 1):

Wait at least the 24 hours. I then use a [poly pad](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Marshalltown-Poly-Fiber-Scouring-Pad/5001934171)
to clean the tile.

A little water helps the process. Then rinse the shower and it will sparkle.